# Sharepoint Online, Follow-up WorkFlow is it possible?

Tags: sharepoint-online, flow

I need to create a workflow on SharePoint online, that automatically sends an e-mail to the user when a new item is added on a list
The problem is that I need the Sharepoint to take the "e-mail information" from a column in the actual list. E.g:
Let`s say we have the following columns:

**Name   /  E-mail            / Status**

I need the SharePoint to automatically pick the information from the "**Email**" column and send the user in the e-mail a notification." 
Is this possible?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

When you select the 'To' field you should see a link called 'Add dynamic content'. Select the link and click on 'See More'. It should show all the fields available for the current item being processed. In below screenshot 'EmailTo' is the people and group column in the list.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

New item is added:

On SharePoint Online are OOTB functions for automatically notifications. 
Look at this link https://support.office.com/en-us/article/get-notified-of-list-changes-in-sharepoint-online-85ca9280-f4b1-485a-a49e-a593ffa62e39 as set for users.

Send to the Email column:

Yes, you can create SharePoint workflow with SharePoint designer, where you will send email to the CurrentItem:Property[Email].

Answer (score 0):

It can be easily done by using SharePoint Workflow.

1. Create a SharePoint workflow for the list which will be triggered when item is created
2. Just add the action “Send an Email” and follow the steps below:

   - Click “this message” in the “Send an Email” action.
   - Click “address book” beside “To” field 。
   - Choose “workflow lookup”. Click “Add”
   - On the workflow lookup prompt, choose “Current Item” in “Source” filed and “Assigned to” in the “Field”
   - Click “OK” and define the body of the email as you like.

Comment: Hi Amit,
Thank you very much for your response
I`m kind of new to SP Online.
I created a workflow that will trigger when an item is added and added the action "Send an Email". But, I can`t seem to find the "this message" button or the "adress book" beside "To".
Am I looking at the wrong thing ?   
I have attached above a screenshot of what I`m seeing.

Answer (score 0):

When you click in the "to" field (or any of the fields), a panel should open up that has a list of the available fields from the "when an item is created" action. However, it will only list fields of the appropriate type. So clicking in "subject" should list all the fields, as that's just a string. Clicking in "to" will list only "person" fields by default. If your "email" field is a person field, all you should have to do is select it. If it is a text field, you will need to click on a button/link that says "see all options" (I think, that's going from memory), at which point it should list all fields. Be warned, however, doing this will make the workflow brittle, as it will fail anytime someone doesn't enter a valid email.

Comment: Hi Mike,

It worked, thank you very much !